# SQL: Gathering count of users who have not logged in past but have logged in reporting week

Tags: sql, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant, teradatasql

I am trying to gather a count of users by mobile platform who haven't logged in the past but may have logged in the reporting week. For this I have built two virtual tables, with reporting_date - it is Saturday of each week, cust_id, app_logins, mobile_platform with one (newmob) collecting all cust_ids who have app_logins =0 and the other (existmob) have cust_ids which have app_logins>0.

My logic is to use all cust_ids in newmob table till prior Saturday of reporting week in question and find is any of those cust_ids logged in till the Saturday of the reporting week, but it doesn't seem to be working.

table structure - newmob
**reportingdate | Cust_id | app_login (0) | mobile_os** (null)

table structure - existmob
**reportingdate | Cust_id | app_login (>0) | mobile_os** (e.g. Android, iOS)

SQL:
--`to_char(last_day(trunc(add_months(trunc(current_date,'D')-1,-12),'D')), 'YYYY-MM-DD')` is the min date in tables

```
Select a.reportingdate, count(distinct a.cust_id) as cust_count, a.mobile_os
from existmob a
where a.reportingdate >= to_char(last_day(trunc(add_months(trunc(current_date,'D')-1,-12),'D')), 'YYYY-MM-DD') + 6
and a.CUST_ID in (select cust_ID from newmob b where b.reportingdate <= a.reportingdate -7)
group by 1,3;
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you use to_char, has `reportingdate` no DATE datatype? You probably need to correlate the `Cust_id`s  the Scalar Subquery, too. Finally you probably dont need two tables, a sinbgle Select should be able to do that

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.  I agree with dnoeth . . . the raw data is probably better for the query.

Comment: @dnoeth  to_char is just a way of cleanup reporting that I produce. The two tables were built so that in order to say how many customers who logged into mobile app in the week of Sep 27 - Oct 3 were from the pool who had ever logged into mobile from Jan 1 2019 till Sep 26. So in essence for every reporting week I am considering the pool from Jan1 2019 till prior week. Hope this helps.